# How to set a locale for Chart.js date labels?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js

I have a Vue component, which renderes different charts using Chart.js. And everything is ok, but I can't set a locale for date labels on X axe.

I've tried to define moment locale at the top of script section of my vue-component, but it brought no results.

```
<script>
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    import 'moment/locale/ru';
    moment.locale('ru');

    console.log(moment.locale()); // it shows needle language: 'ru'!

    import Chart from 'chart.js';

    export default { ... this.chart = new Chart(this.context, config); ... };
</script>
```

^ but... after this try I see on X axe: 'Jul 2013', 'Aug 2013', but not 'Июл 2013', 'Авг 2013'.

Who have faced with such problem and how you have solved it?
Somebody, help, please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I've solved it.**

You should use this adapter https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns to translate months on the chart.